# Save Same Value As Of Its Identity Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have two forms - Credit.aspx & Debit.aspx. Both use the same table. The former saves only credit records and the latter-debit.

**TABLE:**

```
COLUMN   DATATYPE
------------------
 ID         int
 RefID      int
 Credit     Decimal
 Debit      Decimal
```

ID is an AutoIdentity column. 
Using C# to save data.

Only, When saving a **credit record**, I would like to save the ID as also its RefID. The Credit form can save single or many records at a time. If the data type was GUID, we would have known beforehand and is easy, but now is not the case.

The expected output would be

```
ID RefID   Credit  Debit
-------------------------
9   9       2.0     0.0
10  10      3.0     0.0
11   9      0.0     1.0
12   9      0.0     4.0
```

So, is it possible. 
Getting the max(ID) doesnt seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Do you use some sort of ORM or pure Sql? Is your "current record" cached anywhere?

Comment: Its pure Sql and not cached